# For Loop not printing the required result

Tags: linux, bash, shell, bash-scripting

I am trying to use for loop in my script.

I have ssh into a server and moved to the respective directory. Inside
the directory I have multiple files.

I wanted to loop through each file.

the files start with particular name ff

```
ssh -q server@example.com  << EOF
cd /var/dist/s-test/
NAME=ff
echo ${NAME}*   // this is working

for a in ${NAME}*;  // this is not working
do
echo  $a
done

EOF
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace:

```
ssh -q server@example.com  << EOF
```

with:

```
ssh -q server@example.com  <<'EOF'
```

This prevents the shell on the client-side from expanding the here-document.  The script will still be expanded on the server-side.

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
>           [n]<<[-]word
>                   here-document
>           delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>   expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word.  If any part of
>   word  is  quoted,  the  delimiter is the result of quote removal on
>   word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.  **If word is
>   unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter
>   expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion**, the
>   character sequence \<newline> is ignored, and \ must be used to quote
>   the characters \, $, and `. [Emphasis added]